# Different homogeneous ideals give rise to the same closed subscheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to solve Hartshorne's Exercise II.3.12 (Closed Subschemes of Proj S).

> Let $\phi: S \to T$ be a surjective homomorphism of graded rings, preserving degrees. 
>     Show that the open set $U$ of (Ex. 2.14) is equal to $\text{Proj } T$, 
>     and the morphsim $f: \text{Proj } T \to \text{Proj } S$ is a closed immersion.
>
> If $I \subseteq S$ is a homogeneous ideal, take $T = S/I$ and let $Y$ be the closed subscheme of $X = \text{Proj } S$ defined as image of
>   the closed immersion $\text{Proj } S/I \to X$.
>           Show that different homogeneous ideals can give rise the the same closed subscheme. 
>           For example, let $d_0$ be an integer, and let $I' = \bigoplus_{d \ge d_0} I_d$.
>           Show that $I$ and $I'$ determine the same closed subscheme. 
>           We will see later (5.16) that every closed subscheme of $X$ comes from a homogeneous ideal $I$ of $S$
>           (at least in the case where $S$ is a polynomial ring over $S_0$.)

I'm confused by the definition of $I'$ and $I$. Why are they different ideals? Does the discrepancy of $I'$ and $I$ depend on the integer $d_0$ that we are choosing?

Comment: Saturation: $X=V(I)$, $Y=V(L)$, $V(I:L^{\infty})=\overline{X\setminus Y}$. What happens if $L$ is the irrelevant ideal?